# Order of the selected rows are not remembered when I refresh a JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a very strange bug into jsf page which I cannot find. This is the code of the JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="DX-57" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Dashboard"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_sessions.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                    <h:form id="form">

                        <ui:debug />

                        <!-- The sortable data table -->
                        <h:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{SessionsController.dataList}" binding="#{table}" var="item">
                            <!-- Check box -->
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Select" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="highlight(this)" value="#{SessionsController.selectedIds[item.aSessionID]}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="№" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="№" value="№" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{table.rowIndex + SessionsController.firstRow + 1}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Account Session ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Account Session ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="User ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="User ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.userID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity Start Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity Start Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityStart}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity End Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity End Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityEnd}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activity}" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                        <!-- The paging buttons -->
                        <h:commandButton value="first" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>


                        <h:commandButton value="prev" action="#{SessionsController.pagePrevious}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <h:commandButton value="next" action="#{SessionsController.pageNext}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>    

                        <h:commandButton value="last" action="#{SessionsController.pageLast}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <h:outputText value="Page #{SessionsController.currentPage} / #{SessionsController.totalPages}" />
                        <br />

                        <!-- The paging links -->
                        <ui:repeat value="#{SessionsController.pages}" var="page">
                            <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{SessionsController.page}"
                                           rendered="#{page != SessionsController.currentPage}" >
                                <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>   
                            </h:commandLink>
                            <h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                          rendered="#{page == SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                        </ui:repeat>
                        <br />

                        <!-- Set rows per page -->
                        <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                        <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{SessionsController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                        <h:commandButton value="Set" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>
                        <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                        <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{SessionsController.deleteSelectedIDs}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $("tr").not(':first').hover(
                            function () {
                                $(this).css("background","#707070");
                            }, 
                            function () {
                                $(this).css("background","");
                            }
                        );              

                            function highlight(param) {  
                                var row = jQuery(param).parent().parent().children();
                                row.toggleClass('highlited');
                            }        
                        </script>


                    </h:form>                  

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">

                </div>   
            </div>  
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the managed bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
// or import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
/*
 * include SQL Packages
 */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UICommand;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
// or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;

@Named("SessionsController")
@ViewScoped
public class Sessions implements Serializable {

    /*
     * Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver
     */
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;
    // Data.
    private List<ActiveSessionObj> dataList;
    // Rows
    private int totalRows;
    // Paging.
    private static int firstRow;
    private int rowsPerPage;
    private int totalPages;
    private int pageRange;
    private Integer[] pages;
    private int currentPage;
    // Sorting.
    private String sortField;
    private boolean sortAscending;

    /*
     * Constructor
     */
    public Sessions() {
        /*
         * Set default properties
         */
        rowsPerPage = 10; // Default rows per page (max amount of rows to be displayed at once).
        pageRange = 10; // Default page range (max amount of page links to be displayed at once).
        sortField = "ASESSIONID"; // Default sort field.
        sortAscending = true; // Default sort direction.
    }

    public class ActiveSessionObj {

        private String aSessionID;
        private String userID;
        private Date activityStart;
        private Date activityEnd;
        private String activity;
        //private boolean selected;

        public ActiveSessionObj(String aSessionID, String userID, Date activityStart, Date activityEnd, String activity) {
            this.aSessionID = aSessionID;
            this.userID = userID;
            this.activityStart = activityStart;
            this.activityEnd = activityEnd;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public int getFirstRow() {
            return firstRow;
        }

        public String getaSessionID() {
            return aSessionID;
        }

        public void setaSessionID(String aSessionID) {
            this.aSessionID = aSessionID;
        }

        public String getactivity() {
            return activity;
        }

        public void setactivity(String activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public Date getactivityEnd() {
            return activityEnd;
        }

        public void setactivityEnd(Date activityEnd) {
            this.activityEnd = activityEnd;
        }

        public Date getactivityStart() {
            return activityStart;
        }

        public void setactivityStart(Date activityStart) {
            this.activityStart = activityStart;
        }

        public String getuserID() {
            return userID;
        }

        public void setuserID(String userID) {
            this.userID = userID;
        }

        private ActiveSessionObj() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }
    }

    // Paging actions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void pageFirst() {
        page(0);
    }

    public void pageNext() {
        page(firstRow + rowsPerPage);
    }

    public void pagePrevious() {
        page(firstRow - rowsPerPage);
    }

    public void pageLast() {
        page(totalRows - ((totalRows % rowsPerPage != 0) ? totalRows % rowsPerPage : rowsPerPage));
    }

    public void page(ActionEvent event) {
        page(((Integer) ((UICommand) event.getComponent()).getValue() - 1) * rowsPerPage);
    }

    private void page(int firstRow) {
        this.firstRow = firstRow;
        loadDataList(); // Load requested page.
    }

    // Sorting actions ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void sort(ActionEvent event) {
        String sortFieldAttribute = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("sortField");

        // If the same field is sorted, then reverse order, else sort the new field ascending.
        if (sortField.equals(sortFieldAttribute)) {
            sortAscending = !sortAscending;
        } else {
            sortField = sortFieldAttribute;
            sortAscending = true;
        }

        pageFirst(); // Go to first page and load requested page.
    }

    // Loaders ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void loadDataList() {

        // Load list and totalCount.
        try {
            dataList = list(firstRow, rowsPerPage, sortField, sortAscending);
            totalRows = countDBRowNum(); //count the tablerows
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // Set currentPage, totalPages and pages.
        currentPage = (totalRows / rowsPerPage) - ((totalRows - firstRow) / rowsPerPage) + 1;
        totalPages = (totalRows / rowsPerPage) + ((totalRows % rowsPerPage != 0) ? 1 : 0);
        int pagesLength = Math.min(pageRange, totalPages);
        pages = new Integer[pagesLength];

        // firstPage must be greater than 0 and lesser than totalPages-pageLength.
        int firstPage = Math.min(Math.max(0, currentPage - (pageRange / 2)), totalPages - pagesLength);

        // Create pages (page numbers for page links).
        for (int i = 0; i < pagesLength; i++) {
            pages[i] = ++firstPage;
        }
    }

    // Getters ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public List<ActiveSessionObj> getdataList() {
        if (dataList == null) {
            loadDataList(); // Preload page for the 1st view.
        }
        return dataList;
    }

    public int getTotalRows() {
        return totalRows;
    }

    public int getFirstRow() {
        return firstRow;
    }

    public int getRowsPerPage() {
        return rowsPerPage;
    }

    public Integer[] getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public int getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public int getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    // Setters ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setRowsPerPage(int rowsPerPage) {
        this.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
    }

    // Actions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Returns list of ActiveSessionObj items starting at the given first index
     * with the given row count, sorted by the given sort field and sort order.
     *
     * @param firstRow First index of rows to be returned.
     * @param rowCount Amount of rows to be returned.
     * @param sortField Field to sort the data on.
     * @param sortAscending Whether to sort data ascending or not.
     * @return list of ActiveSessionObj items starting at the given first index
     * with the given row count, sorted by the given sort field and sort order.
     */
    public List<ActiveSessionObj> list(int firstRow, int rowCount, String sortField, boolean sortAscending) throws SQLException {

        String SqlStatementSmall = null;
        String SQLStatementLarge = null;

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        int countrow = firstRow + rowCount;
        String sortDirection = sortAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC";

        /*
         * For small tables
         */
        SqlStatementSmall = "SELECT c.*"
                + " FROM (SELECT b.*, rownum rn"
                + " FROM (SELECT a.*"
                + " FROM activeSessionsLog a"
                + " ORDER BY %s %s) b"
                + " WHERE rownum <= ?) c"
                + " WHERE rn > ?";

        /*
         * For huge datatables optimized for perfomance
         */
        SQLStatementLarge = "select * from"
                + " (select asl.*, row_number() over (order by userid asc) r "
                + " from activesessionslog asl)"
                + " where r > 980750 and r <= 980800;";


        String sql = String.format(SqlStatementSmall, sortField, sortDirection);

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<ActiveSessionObj> dataList = new ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj>();

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, countrow);
            ps.setInt(2, firstRow);


            resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            /*
             * take the result from the SQL query and insert it into Array List
             * collection
             */
            dataList = ActiveSessionsArrayList(resultSet);

            conn.commit();
            committed = true;

        } finally {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

        return dataList;
    }

    public int countDBRowNum() throws Exception {

        String SqlStatement = null;

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        SqlStatement = "SELECT count(*) FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG";

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
            try {
                SqlStatement = "SELECT count(*) FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG";

                ps = conn.prepareStatement(SqlStatement);
                resultSet = ps.executeQuery();

                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    count = resultSet.getInt(1);
                }

                conn.commit();
                committed = true;
            } finally {
                if (!committed) {
                    conn.rollback();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        //Returns total amount of rows in table.
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Map the current row of the given ResultSet to ActiveSessionObj.
     *
     * @param resultSet The ResultSet of which the current row is to be mapped
     * to ActiveSessionObj.
     * @return The mapped ActiveSessionObj from the current row of the given
     * ResultSet.
     */
    private ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj> ActiveSessionsArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj> list = new ArrayList<>();


        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(new ActiveSessionObj(
                        rs.getString("ASESSIONID"),
                        rs.getString("USERID"),
                        timestampToDate(rs.getTimestamp("ACTIVITYSTART")),
                        timestampToDate(rs.getTimestamp("ACTIVITYEND")),
                        rs.getString("ACTIVITY")));
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;   
    }

    //get the selected rows
    private HashMap<String, Boolean> selectedIds = new HashMap<>();

    // get the list from the JSF page
    public Map<String, Boolean> getSelectedIds() {
        return selectedIds;
    }

    //delete all selected checkboxes
    public void deleteSelectedIDs() throws SQLException {
        boolean success = false;

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
            try {

                String sqlDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG WHERE ASESSIONID = ?";


                Set<String> keySet = selectedIds.keySet();
                String[] keys = new String[]{};
                keys = selectedIds.keySet().toArray(keys);
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlDeleteQuery);

                for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    ps.setString(1, keys[i]);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    ps.clearParameters();
                    selectedIds.put(keys[i], false); //get(keys[i]) = false;
                }

                conn.commit();
                committed = true;

                //selectedIds.clear();
            } finally {
                if (!committed) {
                    conn.rollback();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

        /*
         * // Get selected items. boolean success = false; try { String
         * sqlDeleteQuery = "";
         *
         * Set<String> keySet = selectedIds.keySet(); Iterator keyIterator =
         * keySet.iterator(); while(keyIterator.hasNext()) { keyIterator.next();
         * }
         *
         * }
         * catch(Exception x) { success = false; } // Do your thing with the
         * MyData items in List selectedDataList.
         */
        //return success; // Navigation case.

        //reload the table
        loadDataList();
    }

    private static Date timestampToDate(java.sql.Timestamp ts) {
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = new Date(ts.getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return d;
    }
}
```

I opened the page and I select some rows I get this:
[image]

But when I press F5 I'm redirected to page 1

[image]

It's very strange because the selected rows are changed. I use hash to remember which rows are selected. It seems that the position into the hashmap is changed.
I changed to `static` the `firstrow` value into the managed bean. Then I get a second problem: the opened page is shared between the clients - when a second browser opens the page the same page of the pagination will be opened.

I tested other solution - I changed the the scope of the bean to SessionScope. I removed the static variable. But the problem of the selected rows is not fixed. I still get the old problem with the position of the selected rows.

Maybe the problem is the hashmap.

private HashMap selectedIds = new HashMap<>();

I suspect that this hashmap is correct. The index of the row of the `h:datatable` must be remembered into the hashmap. How I can fix this problem?

Best Wishes
Peter

Comment: just wondering if you use LinkedHashMap instead og hashmap?

Comment: I will try it next days.

Comment: As Daniel pointed out, use LinkedHashMap. That should solve your problem

Comment: Guys, the `HashMap` is definitely not the problem here.

Comment: @BalusC It was just a wild guess... I haven't read the entire question cause it was a way to long so this the first thing I thought of... so I decide to throw a comment...

Comment: Do you have any other guesses when the problem might be?

Comment: That has already been answered/commented in one of your previous questions, but you ignored and dismissed it because it wasn't what "you" want. You were trying to do things HTTP doesn't allow you (invoking an idempotent request by POST). Fixing/workarounding the current problem would cause a new problem everytime like domino. It isn't worh the effort anymore. You basically need to revise the entire approach and highly consider using a component library which has already done the major part of the nasty tasks for you like PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 2):

If instead of passing the `index` on ui, you will pass the `aSessionID`, then the problem can be solved.

Store the selected sessionsID's in a list or map.

```
/**
 * Stores checked accounts for the Selected User
 * */
private List<Account> selectedAccounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
```

Add a flag in SessionsController.dataList type object which will tell whether the item is selected or not.

```
public boolean isSelectedAccount()
{
    return selectedAccount;
}
```

Now, when the data is obtained at the server side, iterate the map/list and for the object that are checked, set the flag to true.

```
for(Account account : customerAccounts){
    if(selectedAccounts.contains(account)){
    account.setSelectedAccount(true);
        }}
```

On the UI, use this flag to decide whether to show the item as selected or not.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="accounts" value="#{row.selectedAccount}">
```

Also, whenever any object is selected or deselected, add or remove it from the list/map of selected session id's respectively.

```
selectedAccount.add(sessionId);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem arises because you don't store the current paging position in your session - did you notice that it displays the first page on refresh? And it looks like you may be storing relative (in the page) instead of absolute indexes to selected elements.

Comment: There are two ways of preserving and passing data between GET requests: 1) url - include pagenumber in your url, 2) session - store current page position in user session.